# nhibernate for ASP.NET - Could not add assembly ORM_dscnew

Tags: nhibernate

I am new to nhibernate. I am facing the following problem:

```
Exception thrown: 'NHibernate.MappingException' in NHibernate.dll
NHibernate.MappingException: Could not add assembly ORM_dscnew ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ORM_dscnew' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddAssembly(String assemblyName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddAssembly(String assemblyName)
   at viroffice.ORM_sessionf.Init() in D:\GDrive\Projects\VirOffice\viroffice\DataObjects\ORM_sessionf.vb:line 7
```

While executing the function:

```
 Private Shared sFactory As NHibernate.ISessionFactory

    Private Shared Sub Init()
        Dim config As New NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration()
        Try
            config.AddAssembly("ORM_dscnew")
            sFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory()
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex)

            Exit Sub

        End Try

    End Sub
```

While executing the above function, I am getting the error.

ORM_dscnew.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns = "urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace = "viroffice.DataObjects" assembly = "viroffice">

  <class name = "ORM_dscnew" table="dsc_new">
    <id name = "new_id">
      <generator class = "native"/>
    </id>

    <property name = "vnm" />
    <property name = "vcn_name" />
    <property name = "vref" />
    <property name = "vcn_per" />
    <property name = "vcn_no" />
    <property name = "vcn_email" />
    <property name = "vcn_email1" />
    <property name = "vrmks" />
    <property name = "vstatus" />
    <property name = "vapp_id" />
    <property name = "vmob_ver" />
    <property name = "vchg_code" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Kindly advice what needs to be done?

Comment: did you have made the hbm.xml file as embadded resource

Comment: Yes. It has been set as embedded resource.

Answer (score 0):

Using `AddAssembly("ORM_dscnew")` result in a call to `System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("ORM_dscnew")`. And in your case, the .Net Framework is unable to find your assembly and yields a `FileNotFoundException`.

NHibernate just wrap it in a `MappingException`. The root trouble is your assembly being not found (or one of its dependencies...). [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=netframework-4.7#System_Reflection_Assembly_Load_System_String_) states the assembly name should be a long name, and your code only supply the simple name, so maybe that is your issue.

Anyway, personally, I favor adding an assembly by getting it from a type contained in it. Of course, this implies your factory will need a reference to such a type.

```
config.AddAssembly(typeof(ATypeInORM_dscnew).Assembly);
```